# Spring STS error while including Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am new to Java and Spring MVC. I am trying to include spring Mongodb data by using following code in pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But Iam getting follwing error :

/***************************************************************************/

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":description, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":url, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement}' is expected.

/**************************************************************************/

Here is my pom.xml :

/#############################################################################/
    
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-context
            ${org.springframework-version}
            
                
                
                    commons-logging
                    commons-logging
                 
            
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-webmvc
            ${org.springframework-version}

```
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

/############################################################################/

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I looked at mvn repository and the maximum version number is 1.0.4.RELEASE. Are you using a different repository?

Comment: @Chetter Hummin : I have used dependency from following link: http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb#documentation

Comment: Please try 1.1.0.M1 as the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that your `pom.xml` has errors- it's not following the xml schema.

Without seeing the whole file, it's tricky to say the exact cause, but I'm guessing you're missing the opening `<dependencies>` tag.

Here's an example from [the maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM).

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <mavenVersion>2.1</mavenVersion>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```